# Spring Scheduled working without being instantiated

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I'm reading a code and it's using Spring Scheduled

```
@Component
public class TaskWebSocketClient {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000, initialDelay = 10000) 
    void start() {
        try {
            WebSocketPush.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the searching of Visual Studio code and the word "TaskWebSocketCliente"
never been used again. So the class "TaskWebSocketClient" never was been instantiated, but debugging I resolve that the @Scheduled is working. So how a code can run a Scheduled on a class which the class never was instantiated?

Comment: [@Component](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-classpath-scanning) makes it a Spring managed bean, e.g., the Spring framework instantiates and manages the life of the instance.

Comment: But the word "TaskWebSocketCliente" never was been used in the code. It doesn't need use to do a @Autowired TaskWebSocketClient or applicationContext.getBean(TaskWebSocketClient .class) at least one time to use the scheduled method?

Comment: Nothing else depends on it, which is okay.  @Scheduled, managed by Spring, triggers the method.

Comment: So if i have some scheduled methods, all they go run automatically? I thought I need instanciated the class and execute the method to initialize my scheduled method